# Balanced Binary Search Tree Implementation

Tags: c++

If STL map,set are internally using balanced binary search tree for its implementation , should it not be possible to use map or set to represent BBST ?

I need the BBST data structure, can I not use any of the mentioned associative container to implement it or I have do it from scratch ?

Thanks

Comment: It depends. What is the problem you try to solve? What is the use-case? If `std::map` or `std::set` fits your requirements, then by all means use them, but otherwise just don't try to shoehorn them into something where they don't really fit. Finally, if you are supposed to create a tree as part of a school-assignment or similar, then you should of course create your own structures and functions.

Comment: What particular interests you in BBST?

Answer (score 1):

The data structure is a red black tree, which is self balancing and guarantees you a `O(log(n))` time for search/insert/delete. If you need operations beyond the ones that map supports (something like rank and select) you will need to implement your own tree, otherwise you are good to use map.

Comment: What is hard for me to apprehend is how to represent the parent child relationship through map/multimap ? Can I store elements inside the map that represent the hierarchy in the tree and print them as a tree structure. I hope I managed to explain my confusion ?

Comment: @user1355185, no. The information about child/parent node relationship is incapsulated. You cannot know neither what node is parental for a given one nor what childs it has.

Comment: Since the word "black" appears exactly *zero* times in the C++ standard (11 and 14), how do you justify the contention that maps and sets are red-black trees? What an implementation does has *no* bearing on what the standard requires.

Comment: @paxdiablo the documentation states it is usually implemented with red-black trees http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Documentation of what exactly? The cppreference site is hardly an authoritative source, doubly so now since it's introducing its own biases. No, I think I'd prefer to rely on the standard myself. In any case, it's a far cry from "... *usually* implemented as" and your contention "the data structure *is* ..." so I'd suggest you clarify that. It's no different to those that state `qsort` is a quick-sort when, in fact, it could be as brain dead as a bubble sort as far as the C standard gores.

Comment: STL does not provide any generic tree or graph structures although maps and sets are generally implemented as balanced binary tree. So it sound like we can use map to represent balanced binary search tree structure.

Comment: Having said that, the standard *does* mandate the complexity of certain operations (logarithmic for element access for example) so that bit is correct at least, though you may want to specify *what* operations are of that complexity.

Comment: I am kind of lost in translation here. Lets analyse the following scenario: iFriend["Aloha"] = 1; iFriend["Mama"] = 2; iFriend["Mia"] = 3; Since std::map uses balanced binary search tree internally, how would the above three elements be represented as tree hierarchies. Some image/diagram would be appreciated.